# Entity Framework is looking up a nonexistent table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

For the last few days I've been struggling with this problem where Entity framework will look for a nonexistent table. I have no idea why It's doing this either. I attempted to do a code first approach with an existing database, and it's worked absolutely fine as a replacement for all my gateways except 3. All 3 of which deal with this one particular POCO called Student. The POCO class is as follows:

```
public class Student
{
    public Guid StudentId { get; set; }
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; }
    public String Grade { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CourseOffering> CourseOfferings { get; set; }
}
```

My context files is:

```
class GatewayContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Course> Course { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CourseType> CourseTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CourseOffering> CourseOfferings { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Staff> Staff { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<CourseOffering>()
            .HasMany(x => x.Students)
            .WithMany(x => x.CourseOfferings)
        .Map(x =>
        {
            x.ToTable("Students");
            x.MapLeftKey("StudentId");
            x.MapRightKey("CourseOfferings");
        });
    }
}
```

And my code calling in the gateway using these is:

```
        try
        {
            GatewayContext context = new GatewayContext();
            var students = from p in context.Students
                           select p;
            var studentList = new List<Services.Proxy.TransferObjects.Student>();
            foreach (var student in students)
            {
                studentList.Add(student);
            }
            return studentList;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
```

The error this gives me is: "An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details." when using the above code, and when I'm looking the CourseOfferings which contains a Students field for the enrolled students it gives me the error: "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host". When I debug my code I noticed that it appears to be looking for a nonexistent dbo.Students1 table for some reason. Upon further inspection, I do not specify this, or even mention a Students1 in any of my code anywhere. Why would Entity Framework look for a Students1 table instead of my Students table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mapping your `many-to-many` table to a table named "Students" :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CourseOffering>()
            .HasMany(x => x.Students)
            .WithMany(x => x.CourseOfferings)
            .Map(x =>
            {
               x.ToTable("Students");
               x.MapLeftKey("StudentId");
               x.MapRightKey("CourseOfferings");
            });
```

so when EF attempts to create the actual table "Students", it has to rename it to "Students1".

You  might want to rename your `many-to-many` table to `StudentsCourseOfferings` to follow convention. This should create two tables in your database: `StudentsCourseOfferings` and `Students`

Comment: How might I change this so that it accesses students?

Comment: @NightW. just added that to my answer.